# Adding new objects replaces content of old objects - VueJS Store

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

I'm using the following code to insert a new object into the array 'items'. But the problem is when I insert a new object, it replaces the content of the object that is added just before. In such way, the always contains the same objects, even though added objects are different.

I heard it's due to using 'push' which also passes the reference. How can I fix this is VueJS

**Store.js**

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    value: 1,
    quote: {
      items: [],
      something: ''
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD (state, item) {
      state.quote.items.push(item)
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer myself. The solution is 'stringify the object and parse it back, both using JSON'

```
  mutations: {
    ADD (state, item) {
      item = JSON.stringify(item)
      item = JSON.parse(item)
      state.quote.items.push(item)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use `Object.assign` as I have added in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

instead use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator),

```
mutations: {
  ADD (state, item) {
    state.quote.items = [...state.quote.items, Object.assign({}, item)]
  }
}
```

Is spread operator is not needed, you can just do:

```
mutations: {
  ADD (state, item) {
    state.quote.items.push(Object.assign({}, item))
  }
}
```

Comment: @GijoVarghese Possible to create a fiddle of this issue.

Comment: @GijoVarghese All add the code where you are commiting this mutation, may be you are pushing the same item again just by changing it's queue. I will update my answer to handle that case.

Comment: Tried both, not working. The answer I posted is working. The objects are not same. I thoroughly checked