# Vue js 2 list rendering issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have faced an issue when doing a simple shopping cart app in vue js 2
Here is the code I have:

blank cart item array for when I press add to cart button then that particular product will be pushed in this array.

```
data () {
    return {
      cartItems: []
    }
}
```

add to cart method:

```
methods: {
    addToCart (product) {
      product.quantity += 1
      this.cartItems.push(product)
    }
}
```

Template view:

```
<ul>
   <li v-for="item in items">
        <pre>
            {{item.name}} -- {{item.quantity}}
        </pre>
    </li>
</ul>
```

in the browser, I got this:

[image: right side 1 and 2 value is the quantity of that product]

*note: right side 1 and 2 value is the quantity of that product*
but I want something like this.

[image: right side 1 and 2 value is the quantity of that product]

*note: right side 1 and 2 value is the quantity of that product*

If I use vue js 1 instead of vue js 2 then same code gives me browser view like 2nd screenshot I attached.

Please, anybody, help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you push your product to array both times.
Check if product exists in cartItems array, if not - add, else - update product quantity

Comment: Can you explain me little clearly? can you give me some example that will be a big help for me.

Comment: Thanks, brother you have done a great help for me. Actually, I have missed those "indexof" logic that you have done. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

How du you create the new products? Do you reference the same object when calling `addToCart` or do you do some kind of deep copy or extend? If your adding the same reference multiple times they will all have the same quantity.

`v-for="item in items"` this should be `ìf cartItems` if you are not using pseudo code as example.

Comment: Can you explain me little clearly? can you give me some example that will be a big help for me.

Comment: It depends on the source of your movies. You need a new object or both show the same quantity. They have a similary problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611369/adding-new-objects-replaces-content-of-old-objects-vuejs-store

Answer (score 0):

that is because you increment number of product and again after that you  push same product to list . you should check if that item is in the list or not